# Why is intersect giving blank layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have two shapefiles. One is broken into the regions I need to use, the other has much more detail along the coast line. I'd like to use either intersect or clip to get a more detailed coastline on the eastern edge of the map, but I wind up with a blank layer with both.

With `vector > geoprocessing tools > intersect` the new layer is empty no matter how I arrange the settings. If I use `vector > geoprocessing tools > clip` and put the big unified polygon as the "input vector" I wind up with the opposite of what I want -- a new layer that has one big polygon and no coastal detail. What I want is a layer of small polygons *with* coastal detail. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm working in QGIS, though if this would be easier to do in PostGIS I can also use CartoDB.

[image: broken into regions]
[image: one big poygon]

Comment: Try using **Union** (_Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Union_), this combines the two layers along with their attributes so you should get both the regions **and** the coastal lines.

Comment: The problem is that on the East side, the regions extend past the coastal line.

Comment: Most likely either the two layers do not have the same CRS or there is an invalid geometry.

Comment: Sadly, I can't test the answers anymore.